# when use a Custom View? - Android

Tags: android, layout, view

I'm uptading my Android game. I've seen that for games, developers should use Custom Views. But why and when should I use Custom View instead of using Layout XML?

Comment: Custom View inflate xml?

Comment: You use (actually code) custom Views when you need to use something that is not offered by Android's SDK. If you can achieve what you need with "layout XML" then it is **not** a Custom View.

Comment: I mean a Java class that extends View class

Comment: So for a simple Menu (like a title, and a play button) I have to use layout XML instead of creating a new java class which extends View class?

Comment: You can still use XML in custom views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom view are useful for some cases:

- create something non-trivial visually speaking - meaning you want to draw something yourself to the screen, for instance- graph.
- Gain performance - this is probably the main reason for Games - layouts can be heavy on performance when they are have deep nesting (inflating, layouting multiple views inside each other, overdrawing when layouts overlaps each other), you can solve those issues by drawing yourself to the screen using Custom views.
  Additionally, with custom views you can draw something directly to the screen using the GPU with the benefits of Hardware accelerated operations.
- Sometimes enforcing complex layouting that adjusting automatically to different devices size is non-trivial/non-possibile mission using xml layout, in Custom views you can create complex dynamic layouting.

Comment: If I have a simple Menu in which there are a title and a play button , should I use custom view? Or is better use layout?

Comment: layout, no need to over complicate when you gain nothing, I've mention some points that you can't achieve (in specific cases) with layout , if layout working for your UI requirement, and no performance issue then layout (which is most of the time like your simple use case)

Answer (score 0):

Custom Views are basically required when you have a special requirement from a view which is not available in android SDK. For ex. for one of my apps i needed a ImageView which can set it's height 1.5x the width that it receives
so i made this customImageView

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView {

    private static final float ASPECT_RATIO = 1.5f;

    public CustomImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = Math.round(width * ASPECT_RATIO);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that I can set it's height 1.5x the width using LinearLayout.LayoutParams if I'm using a Linear Layout

Comment: yes you can,
but here i have a view which doesn't need to call LinearLayoutParams
moreover in my code i was already doing a lot of calculation taking a lot of things in consideration so , this custom view helped me in reducing the hassle
moreover this is a simple implementation just for a reference
a good example of customView would be this library https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview